# Magento 2 - Why my PWA doesn't compile with GraphQl introspection disabled on production environment?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, magento2

After I get one security report, one of the issues is the graphql introspection enabled on the production environment.
The recommendation is to disable the introspection.

We can find the instructions to disable it on the official documentation:

***Disable introspection querying**
Introspection querying is enabled by default. To disable it in production mode to improve security, add the following to your app/etc/env.php file.*

`'graphql' => [ 'disable_introspection' => true, ]`

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/queries/#disable-introspection-querying

After disabled it, when I tried to compile the PWA I got the following error:

> Error: GraphQL introspection is not allowed, but the query contained __schema or __type (... 1 errors total)
> at /home/ritter/projects/ar/ump_pwa_core/ritter/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:54:21

Does anyone know the reason for this error?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to compile my frontend PWA with GraphQl introspection disabled and I got an error.
I was expecting to compile my PWA using my backend in Production mode with introspection disabled and without errors.